# Assign binary value as new attribute based on existing data

Tags: r

I have dataframe that has attribute returnQuantity. It's integer that represent how many items were returned.

```
orderId    returnQuantity
1          5
2          0
3          2
```

I want to create a new attribute isReturned that will hold binary value if any item was returned (0 - Not returned, 1 - Returned). Example below:

```
orderId    returnQuantity    isReturned
1          5                 1
2          0                 0
3          2                 1
```

I'm new to R and I find it really confusing to assign binary value based on returnQuanitity.

I tried with code below:

```
data$isReturned = NA
data[data$returnQuantity <= 0]$isReturned = 0
data[data$returnQuantity > 0]$isReturned = 1
```

but I get error:

```
> data[data$returnQuantity <= 0]$isReturned = 0
Error in `[.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, data$returnQuantity <= 0) : 
  undefined columns selected
> data[data$returnQuantity > 0]$isReturned = 1
Error in `[.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, data$returnQuantity > 0) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

Comment: Swap the order that you use `data[...]$isReturned` to `data$isReturned[...]`.

Comment: Also, you can do it in one line with `data$isReturned <- as.integer(data$returnQuantity > 0)`. Where the `as.integer()` takes the TRUE/FALSE values into 1/0.